# In R, how to create a loop to divide columns in a data frame

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

In R, I would like to create a loop which takes the first 3000 columns of my data frame and writes them into one file, the  next 3000 columns into another file, and so on and so forth until all columns have been divided as such. What would be the best way to do this?  I understand there are the isplit and iterators functions available now via CRAN, but I am really unsure how to go about this.  Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
library(plyr)
max.col <- ncol(x)
l_ply(seq(1, max.col, by=3000), function(i) 
    write.table(x[,i:min(i+2999, max.col)], file=paste("i", i, sep="-"))
)
```

Comment: Thanks Shane for the reply back!  I tried this out, the result is a single file titled "i" with 2456 columns - which I am assuming is the last iteration of the loop? My followup question is how can I now modify this code such that I can give individual names to each of the files that are outputted? For example "i-1", "i-2", "i-3"

Thank you so much for all of your help, it has been very useful! I am an absolute beginner with programing/coding.

Comment: Sorry...my mistake.  I updated it to reflect your output naming convention.

Comment: Thanks Shane! Another quick followup - If I wanted to output each of these files into specific folders - say "i-1" goes to folder "A-1", "i-2" goes to folder "A-2" in a sequential order --- is there a way for me to specify this in the file=paste statement?  Or will I have to write all of the files in one folder and then find a way to copy/move them to the associated folders after?  I am trying to avoid doing this manually, as in the end there will hundreds of such files.  Thank you once again for your detailed & prompt responses - much appreciated!

Comment: @CCA: I recommend digging into the documentation and examples.  For instance, look at `help(write.table)`.  Yes: you can specify a full path in the paste() function call above.  You can do whatever you want there: try experimenting with `paste` too: help(paste).  Incidentally, please accept this as the answer when you are satisfied so that others will know the question is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you'd bother loading plyr... assuming your data frame is df... (stole the wise use of min() from Shane's answer)

```
maxCol <- ncol(df)
for (i in seq(1, maxCol, by 3000)) {
     write.table(df[,i:min(i+2999, maxCol)], "i")
}
```

You may want to edit the write.table command above to add in your preferred formatting.

Comment: `plyr` is unnecessary in this example (could have used almost any apply function), but it's worth knowing in general (which is why I used it for demonstration).  That said, `for` loops allow side-effects so I try to avoid them unless I want to encourage what could result in "bad" behavior.